# Heroku Deploy Failed with Mongodb Atlas

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I've made a NodeJS application with a connection to Mongodb Atlas, and I'm trying to host it on Heroku. Without the Mongodb part, everything worked fine, but now he shows the following errors:

> `2018-04-23T12:41:36.649024+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`
>
> `2018-04-23T12:41:36.649102+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! /app/.npm/_logs/2018-04-23T12_41_36_643Z-debug.log`
>
> `2018-04-23T12:41:36.738462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1`
>
> `2018-04-23T12:41:36.753179+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`
>
> `2018-04-23T12:41:37.064873+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=kweeni-webtechteam1.herokuapp.com request_id=0d9ac421-d1ae-40ab-8ad9-281c5f0af307 fwd="94.226.217.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`
>
> `2018-04-23T12:41:37.312099+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kweeni-webtechteam1.herokuapp.com request_id=d2fabab6-656c-4361-bf90-dee4f5d416ef fwd="94.226.217.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http`
>
> `2018-04-23T12:41:38.105251+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kweeni-webtechteam1.herokuapp.com request_id=46d4de7e-bba9-4203-bac8-2a8764867bc5 fwd="94.226.217.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`
>
> `2018-04-23T12:41:38.841065+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kweeni-webtechteam1.herokuapp.com request_id=d8eddf26-e681-4ea7-b150-25b003218cc5 fwd="184.164.147.9" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http`
>
> `2018-04-23T12:48:05.409334+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=kweeni-webtechteam1.herokuapp.com request_id=326d4d91-f7a2-4ca7-836e-7ea83e5bb6bc fwd="94.226.217.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`
>
> `2018-04-23T12:48:06.027390+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kweeni-webtechteam1.herokuapp.com request_id=04a39775-0c4a-4f83-a3ca-69cfc9239efa fwd="94.226.217.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

I've already checked the `package.json` file for the correct start script, changed the port and added a procfile, but nothing changes.

I also google the H10 code error, they advised to make a new heroku app which I did, but it still doesn't work.

Can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: How did you connected to Atlas ?